# Should logging errors or other such debug information be handled by the API or by the calling application?

Tags: c#, .net, logging

From a design perspective who should be responsible to write out to file error conditions, or other such debug information?

Is it done

1. inside the API (API responsible for both generating and writing out to file the information)

   or
2. in the API only expose publicly the information to the caller and let the calling application deal with logging it and acting on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about "both"?

In general, an API will be used by many consumers. It there is a problem within the API, then it should be logged in a manner that enhances troubleshooting by the API team.

At the same time, if the API returns an error condition back to the caller, then the caller may want to log that fact, for the purpose of troubleshooting the caller's application.

Comment: @erotavlas - I would say that generally writing exception debug info out to file should be done inside innermost catch. After that point the only thing propagated should be the status of the operation with a bit of description.

So, - inside API.
And, preferably, not only write to file, but also send email to support team, in case you DB is down or something of the sort.

API consumer cannot deal API's internal exceptions, writing them out is useless. And incorrect inputs should not cause exceptions inside API.

Comment: @user270576: writing in the innermost catch is a bad idea. It only captures the stack trace up to the point of the catch. You should only catch exceptions (and only the most specific exceptions) when you can do something about them. Logging is something that can be taken care of on subsystem boundaries, so that's where such exceptions should be caught.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, and if you do not do anything about the exception inside the innermost catch, why have the "catch" statement there at all? Having said that, I agree with you on your points: "you should only catch exceptions when you can do something about them" and "take care of exceptions on subsystem boundaries".

Comment: @user270576: I don't believe that you _should_ have the catch statement in the inner areas, unless you're going to actually _do_ something.

Comment: @JohnSaunders, so, essentially, you are saying that catch at subsystem boundary should be your innermost catch and this is the place where you should log debug info, correct? I believe I said the same thing about the logging, the only difference was, I didn't specify where that catch should be positioned.

Comment: @user270576 one way to think about it is that you should catch the exception _at the last possible moment_. If failing to catch the exception at a particular point would lose information, crash the application, prevent you from correcting the problem, or even lose the exception, then that's where you should catch it. If you can omit a try/catch block without having any of the above problems, then you should omit the try/catch block.

Comment: @user270576 an example is in the event handler for a Windows Forms button click. It used to be the case that an unhandled exception in such an event handler would crash the application (this may have changed). But at the time, the implication was that event handlers needed to have try/catch blocks around them.